# How to customize selection handle in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget

I'm trying to customize selection handle in flutter

[image]

Above light blue pair handle is in **SelectionArea** widget.
I'm trying to customize color and shape.

I found **ContextMenuBuilder** can help this. but I couldn't find where can customize the pair.

but how to success this?

Comment: check [selectionControls](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea/selectionControls.html)